# Statistics help on 3 choices

Tags: android, statistics

I'm working on an Android app where, at one point, the user is asked to input whether something helped.

Their options are 'Yes', 'No' and 'Don't Know'; or they could choose to ignore it.

This is for multiple 'somethings' over a date range.

A summary view for a date range shows the percentage of 'Yes', 'No' and 'Don't Know' entered for each 'something'.

I'm also showing the 'Overall Effectiveness' as the percentage of 'Yes' inputs, which I realise is incorrect.

I am thinking of changing that to 'Yes' minus 'No', but that doesn't address the 'Don't Know' inputs.

How would I handle the data so that 'Overall Effectiveness' represents all 3 data inputs?

So, for a 'something' which has a 'Yes' of 25%, a 'No' of 25% and a 'Don't Know' of 50%, would that be an 'Overall Effectiveness' of 0% ? Or would the 'Don't Know' affect that figure at all?

As an additional to that, what graph type, other that Pie, would best display all 3 data?

Comment: Couldn't you just ignore the "dont't knows" and still use a percentage of yes vs. no?

Comment: Thanks, jcw. See my comment to ZeroOne below

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Don't know" is the same as no answer at all, so I'd count the overall effectiveness (call it OE) as `OE = yes / (yes + no)`.

Comment: Thanks ZeroOne. I'm not on solid ground at all with stats like this. The user also has the option to not select a choice, which would become the 'no answer'. Perhaps 'Don't Know' should be better classified as 'Maybe'..

Comment: @DaveSav Perhaps the "Maybe" could also be dubbed as "Partially", then? You could count that as half-a-yes, then, making the formula into `(yes + maybe/2) / (yes + no + maybe)`.

Comment: Possibly. The choice here is whether a new drug worked or not, so the 'Don't Know' / 'Maybe' / 'Partially' needs to have an input on the 'OE'.